# Take the value of the first row met in non-aggregate expressions

Tags: sql, sqlite, group-by

I have a query like this:

```
SELECT PlayerID, COUNT(PlayerID) AS "MatchesPlayed", Name, Role, Team,
       SUM(Goals) As "TotalGoals", SUM(Autogoals) As "TotalAutogoals",
       SUM(...)-2*SUM(...)+2*SUM(...) AS Score, ...
FROM raw_ordered
GROUP BY PlayerID
ORDER BY Score DESC
```

where in `raw_ordered` each row describes the performance of some player in some match, in reverse chronological order.

Since I'm grouping by `PlayerID` what I get from this query is a table where each row provides the cumulative data about some player. Now, there's no problem with columns with aggregate functions; my problem is with the `Team` column.

A player may change team during a season; what I'm interested in here is the *last* `Team` he played with, so I'd like to have a way to tell `SELECT` to take the first value met in each group for the `Team` column (or, in general, for non-aggregate-function columns).

Unfortunately, I don't seem to find any (easy) way to do this in SQLite: the [documentation](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_select.html#resultset) of `SELECT` says:

> If the expression is an aggregate expression, it is evaluated across all rows in the group. Otherwise, ***it is evaluated against a single arbitrarily chosen row from within the group***.

with no suggestion about how to alter this behavior, and I can't find between the aggregate functions anything that just takes the first value it encounters.

Any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SQLite does not have a 'first' aggregate function; you would have to implement it yourself.

However, the documentation is out of date. Since SQLite [3.7.11](http://www.sqlite.org/releaselog/3_7_11.html), if there is a `MIN()` or `MAX()`, the record from which that minimum/maximum value comes is guaranteed to be chosen.

Therefore, just add `MAX(MatchDate)` to the `SELECT` column list.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT PlayerID, COUNT(PlayerID) AS "MatchesPlayed", Name, Role, 
(SELECT Team FROM raw_ordered GROUP BY PlayerID ORDER BY some_date) AS team,
SUM(Goals) As "TotalGoals", SUM(Autogoals) As "TotalAutogoals",
SUM(...)-2*SUM(...)+2*SUM(...) AS Score, ...
FROM raw_ordered
GROUP BY PlayerID
ORDER BY Score DESC
```

Presumably you have some way in your table to order the output such that you can use a subquery to achieve your goal.

Comment: Grouping by `PlayerID` in the subquery defeats its purpose, since the ordering is not considered for non-aggregate columns in a grouped query. Removing the `GROUP BY` in the subquery and adding a constraint to `PlayerID` (i.e. it must be the same in the parent and the child query) it works fine, but it's quite slow...